# C# Reflection error

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm a newbie when it comes to reflection and at the moment it all seems rather confusing so forgive me if some of your replies appear to confuse me a little more!!!

I'm currently trying to write a small script that will clone data held in one data table based on a value and then reinsert said data into the same table, albeit with an amended ID. I am trying to currently use reflection as I need to do this for multiple tables and do not wish to code out an excessive amount of clauses for countless number of tables.

The Code I have written so far for the reflection method is as follows:

```
public static void CopyData(object sourceObject, object targetObject) 
{
    object[] value = new object[1];
    object[] param = new object[0];

    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in sourceObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        PropertyInfo targetPropertyInfo = targetObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);
        if (targetPropertyInfo.CanWrite && targetPropertyInfo.CanRead)
        {
            value[0] = propertyInfo.GetValue(sourceObject, BindingFlags.Public, null, null, null);
            targetPropertyInfo.SetValue(targetObject, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I currently have no problem passing the data I need into this class, HOWEVER I am getting thrown the following error:

```
Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.
```

I believe this had to do with Integer fields used to identify links within the data. It is important that I keep these intact for processing later on down the line.

Can someone please point me in the right direction of a way to solve this issue????

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the error is thrown on this line:

```
targetPropertyInfo.SetValue(targetObject, value, null);
```

In this line `value` is an object array. I assume it should be an int32. Do you in fact mean to do this:

```
targetPropertyInfo.SetValue(targetObject, value[0], null);
```

This would be writing the value you just got out of the other object.

Comment: @Callum: Just to help with your debugging skills once that error came up you should have checked the line it was pointing to and then thought hard about what the types involved were. `value` is the only object there of type `object[]` so you can tell that was your culprit and from then you'd probably have noticed your mistake. In this case `value` doesn't really need to be an `object` array though I aprreciate that you may have other code you have pruned for this question that makes use of the array (and indeed `param` which is unused).